# how to get 2 keys from json if requirments are met

Tags: python, json

I'm working on a project that gives a list of the top 5 live minecraft streamers on Twitch. To create this list I want to get the display_names and viewers from the streams that have the word skyblock or modded in their status and `broadcast_platform` is `live`. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I'm new to python so please don't roast me if it is really easy ;). Thanks in advance for the help

I have tried using

`names = [x['display_name']
            for x in data['streams'][0]['channel']
                if any(s in x.get('status', '').lower() for s in ['skyblock', 'modded'])
]`

But this gives the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` and I don't know how I add a way to check if `broadcast_platform` is `live`

```
'_total':115,
'streams':[  
  {  
     '_id':27188411728,
     'game':'Minecraft',
     'broadcast_platform':'live',
     'community_id':'227ee534-e395-4c02-b7e9-cc0160a7159c',
     'community_ids':[  
        '227ee534-e395-4c02-b7e9-cc0160a7159c'
     ],
     'viewers':503,
     'video_height':720,
     'average_fps':60.0220264317,
     'delay':0,
     'created_at':'2018-01-06T12:42:27Z',
     'is_playlist':False,
     'stream_type':'live',
     'preview':{  
        'small':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lolddog-80x45.jpg',
        'medium':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lolddog-320x180.jpg',
        'large':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lolddog-640x360.jpg',
        'template':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lolddog-{width}x{height}.jpg'
     },
     'channel':{  
        'mature':False,
        'status':'잉여맨 생방송 개꿀잼 아오오니 컨텐츠 (minecraft)',
        'broadcaster_language':'en',
        'display_name':'ㅁ잉여맨',
        'game':'Minecraft',
        'language':'ko',
        '_id':145971530,
        'name':'lolddog',
        'created_at':'2017-01-25T19:06:37.322554Z',
        'updated_at':'2018-01-06T14:06:35.661381Z',
        'partner':False,
        'logo':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/a7439e1e92bae2cb-profile_image-300x300.png',
        'video_banner':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/12d86926b1ed139e-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png',
        'profile_banner':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/lolddog-profile_banner-51fc562927fcd0a9-480.png',
        'profile_banner_background_color':'',
        'url':'https://www.twitch.tv/lolddog',
        'views':64203,
        'followers':6191,
        'broadcaster_type':'',
        'description':'잉여맨의 마인크래프트 신선하고 유쾌한 방송 입니다.'
     }
  },
  {  
     '_id':27187856336,
     'game':'Minecraft',
     'broadcast_platform':'live',
     'community_id':'0b9d06f9-fe5f-4f69-a4c3-2a9ee5604fb7',
     'community_ids':[  
        '0b9d06f9-fe5f-4f69-a4c3-2a9ee5604fb7',
        '227ee534-e395-4c02-b7e9-cc0160a7159c',
        'fd0eab99-832a-4d7e-8cc0-04d73deb2e54'
     ],
     'viewers':422,
     'video_height':900,
     'average_fps':60,
     'delay':0,
     'created_at':'2018-01-06T11:00:20Z',
     'is_playlist':False,
     'stream_type':'live',
     'preview':{  
        'small':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_matrixis-80x45.jpg',
        'medium':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_matrixis-320x180.jpg',
        'large':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_matrixis-640x360.jpg',
        'template':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_matrixis-{width}x{height}.jpg'
     },
     'channel':{  
        'mature':True,
        'status':'Weekend derping !prime - Modern Skyblock 2',
        'broadcaster_language':'en',
        'display_name':'Matrixis',
        'game':'Minecraft',
        'language':'en',
        '_id':32776386,
        'name':'matrixis',
        'created_at':'2012-08-06T17:03:31.398564Z',
        'updated_at':'2018-01-06T14:05:54.989584Z',
        'partner':True,
        'logo':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/matrixis-profile_image-526891ecc78e1d4a-300x300.png',
        'video_banner':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/matrixis-channel_offline_image-efea8977a5d238db-1920x1080.png',
        'profile_banner':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/matrixis-profile_banner-3eb2813de7a4bfdb-480.png',
        'profile_banner_background_color':'',
        'url':'https://www.twitch.tv/matrixis',
        'views':1507379,
        'followers':77924,
        'broadcaster_type':'',
        'description':"I'm a Geek through and through. \rI'll talk about anything technical. \rComputer Engineer by trade. \rGamer for Life."
     }
  },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's great that you edited your question with code, but... python has very specific formatting rules. And without properly formatting the code you posted, it's impossible to read it. Please edit again to format correctly, with correct indentation.

Comment: sorry for that I edited my post again @DavidMakogon

Comment: Hi Oh, as per my understanding your problem: names = [x['channel']['display_name'] for x in data['streams'] if any(s in x['channel'].get('status', '').lower() for s in ['skyblock', 'modded'])]

Comment: @Anup Thanks that fixed my first problem but I'm also trying to make sure that 'broadcast_platform': 'live'. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @ohhey do you mean: names = [x['channel']['display_name'] for x in data['streams'] if any(s in x['channel'].get('status', '').lower() for s in ['skyblock', 'modded']) and x['broadcast_platform'] == 'live']

Comment: @Anup *Please* do everyone a favor and post a proper answer. Unformatted python is unreadable. And answers do not belong in comments. You've now posted two such comments.

Comment: @davidMakogon thank you but commented as per request for other solution.

Comment: @anup with all due respect: you are not being helpful by  posting code as a comment. Made worse since it's python and unusable without proper indentation. I can't imagine why you won't post both comments in a single answer. Comments are for clarification. Meanwhile, what you have posted as comments is unhelpful for any other readers seeking similar assistance. And you've now turned the comments into a discussion with the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get display name as per channel status:

```
names = [x['channel']['display_name'] for x in data['streams'] if any(s in x['channel'].get('status', '').lower() for s in ['skyblock', 'modded'])]
```

And to get display name as per channels status and broadcast platform:

```
names = [x['channel']['display_name'] for x in data['streams'] if any(s in x['channel'].get('status', '').lower() for s in ['skyblock', 'modded']) and x['broadcast_platform'] == 'live']
```